# Finding the range of ints in a scanner

Tags: java, range

```
public int rangeInScanner(Scanner stream) {
    int max = stream.nextInt();
    int min = stream.nextInt();

    while (stream.hasNextInt()){
        if (stream.nextInt() > max) {
            max = stream.nextInt();
        }
        if (stream.nextInt() < min) {
            min = stream.nextInt();
        }
    }
    return max - min;
}
```

Why can't I get this to work. Lets say Scanner stream = new Scanner("5, 4, 3, 2, 1");
I want this to return 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think should be

```
public int rangeInScanner(Scanner stream) {
    int max = stream.nextInt();
    int min = max;

    while (stream.hasNextInt()){
        int curr = stream.nextInt();
        if (curr > max)
            max = curr;
        if (curr < min)
            min = curr;
    }
    return max - min;
}
```

*edit*

You are missing half of the comparisons required, and also possibly generating an exception. If there is an odd number of integers, [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) will throw a [NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Comment: Yep, Scanners are stateful.  Every time you call nextInt() you're moving to the next element, not simply "peeking".

Comment: @DavidATarris: thanks for expressing so clearly the concept. I briefly tried to find the English wording required, but I failed...

Comment: Thank you so much. So basically i need to store the next value before i compare it or else its going too far ahead?